help identifying composite decking brand
I'm repairing an existing composite deck. Most of the parts are composite sleeves over wood and the wood has basically all rotted away inside the sleeves. Some of the parts have cracked due to the stresses put on them without the wood core. I'd love to replace some is the broken components. An exact match is ideal, but honestly even something close would work for me.
I wish there was a store I could go compare, but everything near me is online only for composite decking. Any help is super appreciated.
Here's the photos of the disassembled parts.
